# How to events from azure event hub to azure blob storage using logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub

I want to move events from azure event hub to Azure blob storage using the logic app, can anyone suggest to me how to use with logic app connector, triggers, and action with the designer example.

Note:
Events are json events and need to be stored in blob storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a blank logic app, and use the search assistant to find what you're looking for.

- Typing `event hub` gives:

[image]

where you can provide the connection by providing the name.

- Save the content in a variable.
- You can use `SaveInitialJsonToBlobStorage` to now store this json in a blob storage:
  [image]